# do math operators on each number of array

Tags: typescript

How can i check every number in my array of numbers?

**.ts**

```
    let age = [16, 25, 33];
    
    if(this.age < 18) {
    // do something
    }
    if(this.age > 18) {
    // do something
    }
```

Comment: Typescript and Java are unrelated languages. If you mean [tag:javascript], do not tag [tag:java].

Comment: A `for` loop is always a good start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go for two approaches ->

1. Using the loop where you iterate through all elements and within a nested if block directly executes the conditional statement or function.

   ```
     for(a in age){
      if(a > 18){
       console.log('Less than 18');
       }
      else{
       console.log('More than 18');
       }
     }
   ```
2. Use a 'map()' function and change each element of the array if it is what you need to do.

example -

```
let age = [16, 25, 33];

var modified = age.map( a => {
if(a < 18 ){

return a*a; 

}else{
 return a*a*a;
 }

})

console.log(modified);
// prints - (3) [256, 15625, 35937]
```